# Remove Duplicates from my SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table with the below data.

```
Col1    Col2
 A       B
 B       A
 C       D
 D       C
 E       F
 F       E
```

If the (col1 and Col2) and (col2 and Col1) values are same in the multiple rows, they are considered as Duplicates.In the above example, Col1 and Col2 are same between Row 1 and Row 2, they are considered as duplicates. We need only 1 row among them.

So the output for the above example will be,

```
Col1   Col2
 A      B
 C      D 
 E      F
```

or

```
Col1   Col2
 B      A
 D      C 
 F      E
```

Please help me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

rextester: http://rextester.com/XCYU52032

```
create table tb (col1 char(1), col2 char(1))
insert into tb (col1, col2) values
 ('a','b')
,('b','a')
,('c','d')
,('d','c')
,('e','f')
,('f','e');

with cte as (
    select col1, col2, rn = row_number() over(order by col1)
    from tb
    )

/* 
    select x.* 
      from cte as x
      where not exists (
        select 1 
          from cte as y 
          where y.col2 = x.col1
            and x.rn>y.rn  -- returns col1 in ('a','c','e')
            --and x.rn<y.rn  -- returns col1 in ('b','d','f')
        )

--*/

    delete x 
      from cte as x
      where not exists (
        select 1 
          from cte as y 
          where y.col2 = x.col1
            --and x.rn>y.rn  -- returns col1 in ('a','c','e')
            and x.rn<y.rn  -- returns col1 in ('b','d','f')
        )

select * from tb
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
delete from myTable t1
where col1 > col2 and exists (select 1 
                            from myTable t2 
                            where t2.col1 = t1.col2 and t2.col2 = t1.col1);
```

Comment: This works. There is a small correction in your code. myTable alias should be 't1' in the outer query. Not 't'. Thanks a lot Serg...